# Vert.x - gets stuck after some idle time

Tags: java, mysql, netty, vert.x, event-loop

Below is my code on Vertx. Using SQLclient PreparedQuery to get data from Database, but after 30 mins of idle time it gets stuck.

> Vert.x version - 3.8.0

```
//initialized one on application startup
var mysqlOpts = new MySQLConnectOptions()
        .setHost(jdbcHost)
        .setPort(3306)
        .setDatabase(jdbcSchema)
        .setUser(jdbcUser)
        .setPassword(jdbcPass)
        .setCachePreparedStatements(true);

var mysqlClient = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, mysqlOpts, new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(20 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()));

// called every time on GET request works fine.
// After some idle time say 1hr.The execution at below gets stuck. (The GET request gets stuck).If I kill the process and try again it starts working.
mysqlClient.preparedQuery(SIMPLE_SELECT_QUERY ,tuple , ar -> {
    // some code here
 });
```

Please advise what needs to be done even after some idle time. We do not get request all the time.

Comment: what do you mean by "gets stuck"? any exceptions/warnings in the logs?

Comment: @injecteer no exceptions/warnings in logs, silently getting into some kind of loop and not able to come out.